# Is $\log{(0.99\dots)}$ negative or it is $ 0$?

Tags: logarithms, substitution

It is known  that $0.99\dots =1$, but I'm afraid to say by substitution if it is allowed  that $\log{(0.99\dots)}=0$ , then is it negative or equal $0$ ?

Comment: Yes, substitution is allowed and $\log(0.\overline{9})=0$.

Comment: The underlying question does not really have anything to do with logarithms or the fact that $0.999\cdots = 1$. Generalizing the question, what you are asking here is: if $a = b$ and $f$ is a function this is it always true that $f(a) = f(b)$?

Comment: Actually it's not even just functions, but *any* statement that holds for $a$ still holds if $a$ is replaced by $b$.

Answer (score 6):

$0.9999...$ is *exactly* one. Is not an approximation or some other construct; the symbol $0.999...$ and the symbol $1$ are the exact same object, and you can write one or the other in any context

Comment: Actually the *symbols* are not the same object; one is a single digit, while the other is a certain combination of digits and dots. What is the same object is the *number* those symbols describe.

Comment: @celtschk sure, that’s what I meant with same object. But nothing wrong with being more precise :)

Answer (score -2):

Another approach:

$S_n:= 9(1/10)+$

$9(1/10)^2 +9(1/10)^3...+9(1/10)^n.$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n =1$,

the limit of the infinite geometric series with $r=(1/10)$.

Since $\log$ is a continuous function :

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \log(S_n) =$

$\log(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n)=0.$

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the question asked . Continuity of log is irrelevant and so is the fact that those two limits are the same

Comment: To demonstrate the pitfalls in this approach, note that $\lfloor 0.999\ldots \rfloor = 1$.

Comment: Hurkil. Can you be a bit more precise? Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas His point is that that function is not continuos, hence you get different results for the limit of the function of the sequence (which is 0) and the function of the limit of the sequence (which is one). The fact that the two limits are different though does not matter. $0.9999... = 1$ and that's all there is to it. The continuity of log (or the non-continuity of the floor operator) are irrelevant

Comment: Ant.I do not yet delete this answer, perhaps instructive (pitfalls(!)).The way to go is your answer.Thanks for your explanation, Peter

Comment: Deleting it or not is your choice. Btw, if you want people to read your messages, you need to ping them by using @ + name. So if you want to ping me you need to write @Ant